# Custom Social Media Links for Subsites

Tags: master-page, sub-site

I am fairly new to sharepoint so I hope this isn't too stupid of a question.  I have a site with several subsites.  Currently there are social media links (facebook and twitter) that link to the same pages for each subsite, this is set in the main master page for all the subsites.  Several of the owners of the subsites have their own social media accounts that they would like their sites to be indivisually linked to but I am not sure how to customize this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move site specific content out of the Master Page. In those areas place a webpart zone. For each site edit the page, add web part -> add content editor web part -> Place custom links.